# Meaning of number in string produced by pkill

Tags: linux, shell

When I kill process with pkill I see such strings:

```
[2]+  Killed    nohup ./manage.py goods_import --farnell > logs/farnell.txt 
[3]-  Killed    nohup ./manage.py goods_import --farnell > logs/farnell.txt
```

I'm wondering what does numbers and plus/minus signs on beginning of string  mean?
In case above:

`[3]-` and `[2]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number in square bracket is the **job number** in the job control table when job was put in background.

As per `man bash` (**JOB CONTROL** section):

> In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command),
>   the **current  job**  is  always flagged with a `+`, and the **previous job** with a `-`.